# firebase: date object methods return the wrong values

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to decompose a date I got from Firestore. Here's the source code:

```
exports.computeStatistics = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    let validatedViolations = [];
    const getValidatedViolations = db.collection("violations").where("validated", "==", true).get().then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            validatedViolations.push({
                type: doc.data().type,
                date: doc.data().date.toDate()
            });
        })
    });

    getValidatedViolations.then(snapshot =>{
        return console.log(validatedViolations[0].date.getMonth(),validatedViolations[0].date.getDay());
    })

});
```

the date value is the following:

```
2019-11-14T00:00:00.000Z
```

but the outputs of the `getMonth()` and `getDay()` methods are respectively `10, 4` which are wrong.
What's the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you get is "correct", in the sense that it corresponds to your code:

As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), `getMonth()`:

> returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a
>   zero-based value (**where zero indicates the first month of the year**).

and, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), `getDay()`:

> returns the day of the week for the specified
>   date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.
>
> ....
>
> An integer number, between 0 and 6, corresponding to the day of the
>   week for the given date, according to local time: 0 for Sunday, 1 for
>   Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on

---

Since, November the 14th 2019 is a Thursday you get 10 (11 - 1) and 4.

---

Instead of `getDay()` you should use [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), and you should note that with `getMonth()`, zero indicates the first month of the year.